# Latest WSUS Server Sync expired Group Policy Preference CSEs

Tags: group-policy, wsus

Last night's sync of my WSUS server expired the [KB943729](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943729) updates for all OS versions. I can't seem to find a reason for this. I assume they're due to be replaced, but haven't been yet.

Unless I'm missing something, clients that have already installed the KB943729 package will not spontaneously remove it now that it's expired, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked on any of my WSUS servers yet this morning to see if I'm seeing those updates expired myself.

Regardless, clients will not remove expired updates that are already installed.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. The replacement packages arrived with last night's sync.